# Trouble using .net 7 preview on IIS

Tags: .net-7.0

I installed .net 7 preview on Windows Server 2012 R2, but the installed version doesn't show in the list of runtimes.

```bash
dotnet --list-runtimes
```

Also running a test app on IIS didn't work. I get this message in the event-log:

```
Could not find 'aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll'. Exception message:
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '7.0.0-preview.7.22375.6' (x64) was not found.
  - The following frameworks were found:
      2.2.5 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      3.1.7 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      5.0.2 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      6.0.0 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.
```

Is this issue fixable somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up installing the dotnet 7 rc1 sdk in addition to the runtime and it was recognized by

```
dotnet --list-runtimes
```

The web app in IIS recognized the runtime afterwards.